miniexcel 1.31.3 how to add two datatable to same sheet?
I am trying to add two datatables to same sheet using miniexcel 1.31.3 version. Checked the documentation but did not find anything.
I do not want to use SaveAsByTemplate.
Please help.
    Dim tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"MiniExcel-{Guid.NewGuid()}.xlsx")

    Dim sheets As New DataSet

    sheets.Tables.Add(getInvoiceData())

    Dim Config As New OpenXmlConfiguration With {
        .TableStyles = TableStyles.Default,
        .AutoFilter = True,
    }

    SaveAs(tempPath, sheets, configuration:=Config)

